# Create and print a Linked list

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, linked-list

```
#include <iostream>     
      
using namespace std;
struct node   
{      
    int num;   
    node * next;   
};
//Create a list, if list is not empty have at least first middle and last node
void cList (node *);
//inserts a node
void iANode(node *);
//Inserts in order
void iIOrder(node *);

void main(){
    int numM;   
    node *list, *current;   
    list = new node;   
    current = list;
    cout<<"Input"<<endl;
    cin>>numM;

    //creates a list
    void clist(node * record){
        node * head = new node;
        (*head).d1=0;
        (*head).next =0;
        return head;
    }

    //inserts a node
    void iANode(node * record)
    {
        (*newnode).next = (*pred).next;
        (*pred).next= new node;
        ++(*phead).counter;
    }

    //inserts in order
    void iIOrder(node * new node, node*head){
        node *pred = head;
        int i = (*new node).d1;
        node*succ=(*pred);
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a linked list and sorting it after each user input.

Currently getting a whole lot of compile errors. Id appreciate if someone could help and point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.
Compile Errors:

> Local function definitions are illegal for "cList" and "iANode"
>
> ";" missing after "node * record)"in cList
>
> Expecting ")" after node in "void iIOrder(node * new node"

Comment: Move the function definitions out of your main() function.

Comment: If you desperately need a *list* there's [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). But I rather recommend [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: What compile errors? What is it that you don't understand about them?

Comment: `void main` is bad. `int main` is good. Also lots of memory leaks.

Comment: Also (assuming you are trying to learn C++), you are writing this like C. Instead, you should have a `class` with member functions.

Answer (score 1):

1. use **struct node *next**, instead of node *next. Same applies to *list and *current
2. some compilers does not accept void main(), try using int main()
3. put all function implementation outside main()
4. declare *current and *list as global variables (outside main())
5. C++ is case sensitive, cList is different from clist. fix cList implementation
6. not an error, but use -> operator: head->num = 0;
7. there is no field d1 in structure node (function cList and iIOrder). Use field num.
8. to nullify a pointer use NULL instead of 0
9. cList function is void, but you are returning a pointer, change return value
10. in iANode function you are using a lot of undeclared variables. You probably want to use *list, *current and *record.

There is a bunch of analythic errors, but you asked for syntax errors. Maybe you will find more errors later, try to fix theses first.